# Maps and Lists in Java

Tags: java, list, maps

```
NodeList nList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("dep");
Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> depMap = new HashMap<String, List<Map<String, String>>>();
for (int temp = 0; temp < nList2.getLength(); temp++) {
  Element el = (Element)nList2.item(temp);
  String type=el.getAttribute("type");
  Node nNode = nList2.item(temp);
  if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
    List<Map<String,String>> depList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    String governor = getTagValue("governor", eElement);
    String dependent = getTagValue("dependent", eElement);
    Map<String, String> govdepmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    govdepmap.put(governor, dependent);
    depList.add(govdepmap);
    List<Map<String,String>> flist = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
    flist.add(govdepmap);
    depMap.put(type, flist);
  }
}
```

I wrote this code but the problem is whenever the loop runs it replaces the List which was already stored in depMap. I want that it should append the new Map in the List retrieved from depMap and not replace it.

Comment: This code is very hard to follow. I suggest refactoring it. I'd start with moving List<Map<String, String>> into a class and exposing necessary functionality required. Once that's done you can start breaking down what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

so instead of creating new list in each iteration you need to get the list from map and `add()` items to that list

Change

```
List<Map<String,String>> flist = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
```

to

```
List<Map<String,String>> flist = depMap.get(type);
if(flist == null){
 List<Map<String,String>> flist = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
}
```

Comment: {neg=[{going=not}, {going=not}, {going=not}], det=[{car=a}, {pencil=a}, {car=a}, {pencil=a}, {car=a}, {pencil=a}], conj=[{going=buying}], xcomp=[{going=buy}, {going=buy}, {going=buy}], nsubj=[{going=I}, {buying=i}, {going=I}, {buying=i}, {going=I}, {buying=i}], aux=[{going=am}, {buy=to}, {buying=am}, {going=am}, {buy=to}, {buying=am}, {going=am}, {buy=to}, {buying=am}], dobj=[{buy=car}, {buying=pencil}, {buy=car}, {buying=pencil}, {buy=car}, {buying=pencil}], conj_but=[{going=buying}, {going=buying}], cc=[{going=but}]}

gives this output but this is wrong as they are appending a lot of times.

Comment: Hey Jigar this code was right but you see the problem here it's doing the task three times for every list.

Comment: _it's doing the task three times for every list._ elaborate please

Comment: means see {going=not} is getting appended three times in neg and see in aux {going=am},{buy=to},{buying=am} is getting repeated three times. If this appends only one time then it would be perfect

Comment: Because you have taken List<Map> which can have multiple entries of same key value

Comment: Hey how would i go about looking all the "dep" tags in my XML file under the tag "basic-dependencies". This was the main problem I have to look for "dep" tags only under "basic-dependencies".

Comment: Please create new post for new question

Answer (score 0):

Move the initialization of `flist`, `govdepmap` and `depList` outside the for-loop.

Comment: The problem is that flist that is retrieved from the depMap is added everytime when it is run. I want that the new old flist to be replaced by a list which includes elements of flist retrived + new elements and put that in depMap

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to following code.

```
    NodeList nList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("dep");
    Map<String, List<Map<String, String>>> depMap = new HashMap<String, List<Map<String, String>>>();
    List<Map<String,String>> flist = null;
    for (int temp = 0; temp < nList2.getLength(); temp++) {
      Element el = (Element)nList2.item(temp);
      String type=el.getAttribute("type");
      Node nNode = nList2.item(temp);
      if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
        List<Map<String,String>> depList = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        String governor = getTagValue("governor", eElement);
        String dependent = getTagValue("dependent", eElement);
        Map<String, String> govdepmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        govdepmap.put(governor, dependent);
        depList.add(govdepmap);
        if(flist == null){
            flist = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        }
        flist.add(govdepmap);
        depMap.put(type, depList);
      }
    }
```

Comment: This puts the same list in all the keys of depMap.

Comment: i checked but it's again replacing the old list. By the way where are you retrieving the old list in this code?

Comment: Hey Thanx a lot everyone for trying, my problem is sovled